# Deciding related tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes I face a problem which *directly* belongs to tag_1 but I get a feeling that people following tag_2 might also be able to answer it. Problem is tag_2 is not *directly* related to the problem.

For example:

I am having a problem related to a basic drawing primitive. This problem is generic and should probably belong to [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm). But I somehow feel that people following [opengl](/questions/tagged/opengl) might also be able to give some hints about it, if not solve it.

Should I include the second tag type as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, but it wouldn't hurt to find a more specific tag than something like [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm), [drawing](/questions/tagged/drawing) would be a good place to start.  I'd work to find even more specific ones that those who watch [opengl](/questions/tagged/opengl) would be interested in.